# A query on Veronese mapping

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> The Veronese mapping defined as usual on some $P^n$. Then it is certainly regular.
>   I want to prove that the inverse map to this map is also regular.

I have an idea to use projections with respect to some nonzero coordinate (locally) and its multiple to get its preimage and since projections are polynomial maps and hence it is regular. Is my idea correct?

> And in this map $f:k[y_0,y_1,...,y_N]\longrightarrow k[x_0,...,x_n]$ sending $y_i$ to a form $M_i$ of degree $d$ how can we say that the kernel is homogeneous ideal?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please read the [MathJax FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: To get an idea of what is going on why don't you first study the specifc Veronese mapping $P^2\to P^5$.

Comment: Thanks..for correct editing....@user26857

Comment: I have studied it and hence have that idea as i mentioned

Comment: Ok. Is that immediately generalizable, or do you need to take a look at another example case first?

Comment: I have gone through a few other cases as well..hence i mentioned my idea..kindly tell me is it correct?